# Optimization over not bounded and not closed set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, elementary-set-theory, optimization

Could someone please explain me why maximizing a function f(x,y)=x+2y over a S={(x,y): x is between [0,2],2x+y<1} might cause problem ?
What happens when we try to maximize a function f(x,y) over the S if we know first partial derivative with respect to x and y is >0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much simpler example that should shed some light:
what happens if you try to maximize $f(x)=x$ on the set $S=\{x:0<x<1\}$?

Comment: I understand your point but your example is pretty straightforward. Could you explain with my question? why is it not bounded and not closed and why is this a problem?

Comment: A strict inequality is usually a pretty telling sign you're not dealing with a closed set. Here we have $2x+y<1$. Imagine if you were just maximizing $f(x,y)=y$ over this set. Then (0,0.99) is pretty good, (0,0.9999) is better.... but you can never maximize it. Here something similar is happening. The "danger" with dealing with optimizing over a set that is not closed is that the function might keep increasing as you approach the boundary.

Comment: That was quite helpful. I understood very well but what is the problem with unbounded sets?

Comment: It's very similar, try maximizing $f(x)=x$ over the set of all positive numbers. In this particular case unboundedness isn't causing any troubles, but it would if you were, say, dealing with maximizing $f(x,y)=-y$.

Answer (score 0):

If you maximize the objective function say with gradient ascent without caring about the constraint. It might happen that you go out of the feasible region. For your case we can see that the objective function is maximized at $(+ \infty, + \infty)$. However it does not satisfy the constraints.

Sometimes you can get lucky that the optimal point already satisfies the constraint.

To check optimality for constraint optimization problem you can use KKT Conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's maximize over the closure of your $S$:
$$
\bar{S} = \{ (x,y): x \in [0,1], 2x + y \le 1 \}
$$
The objective function is $ x+ 2y$, so it is increasing in both arguments, so the condition $2x + y \le 1$ will bind, since otherwise either $x$ or $y$ could have been further increased, and the objective further increased.  This implies $2x+y = 1$, or $ y = 1-2x$, and your problem can be rewritten
$$
\max_{x \in [0,1]} x + 2(1-2x)
$$
for which the solution is $x^*=0$, implying $y^* = 1$.  However you want to solve it, using a Lagrangian and KKT or whatever, this is "obviously" the answer when considering $\bar{S}$: $x^* =0$, $y^*=1$, for an objective value of $2$.

The problem is that in $S$, this point is "missing", because $2*0+1 <1$ fails.  That means that your function achieves a supremum of $ 2$ over the set $S$, but there is no point in $S$ for which $f(x,y) = 2$.  This means that you can get arbitrarily close to the supremum with a sequence $(0,y_n)$ with $y_n = 1-\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 1$, with the value $2(1-\frac{1}{n})$ strictly increasing at each step, but you never reach the maximum.

At a more abstract level, your problem does not satisfy the assumptions of Weierstrass' extreme value theorem: every upper semi-continuous function on a compact set achieves a maximum. You have a "hole" in your non-compact $S$ which is exactly where the maximizer "would be" (it is in the closure of $S$ but not $S$ itself.).